# Dropdownlist value is null after posting to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I can get all Roles plus actually Role for chosed user, but then When I posting to EditUser action, then Dropdownlist sends null.
I mean When the form posts to my controller, I get null from DropDownList.

Here is my Model

```
public class EditUserViewModel
    {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public List<SelectListItem> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
      public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is Action

```
[HttpGet]
            public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(string id)
            {
                EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();
                model.ApplicationRoles = RoleManager.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = r.Name,
                    Value = r.Id
                }).ToList();


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var role = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                        var existingRole = role.First();
                        string existingRoleId = RoleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == existingRole).Id;
                        model.Id = user.Id;
                        model.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                        model.ApplicationRoleId = existingRoleId;
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name", model.ApplicationRoleId); 
                    }
                }
                return PartialView("_EditUser", model);
            }
```

And here is DropDownlist from _EditUser.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Role typ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
                <div class="col-md-12" title="Ange antal datorer som finns i lager">
                    @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Getting null Only from DropDownList, not from  @Html.EditorFor
/Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show you model and the signature of the POST method (does your model really contain a property named `RoleId`? - based on the code in your get method your view code will be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationRoleId, Model.ApplicationRoles)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. Now it's working . But I don't know how to accept your answer

Comment: I have not given an answer (and will not until you edit your question as I asked)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aha Ok, now I have edited with ViewModel ..;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms post back the name/value pairs of their successful form controls. Your generating a `<select>` element with `name="RoleId"` but you model does not contain a property named `RoleId`. Since you want to bind the selected option to the `ApplicationRoleId` role property, then you view needs to be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationRoleId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationRoleId, Model.ApplicationRoles)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ApplicationRoleId)
```

Notes:

1. Your current `@Html.Label(..)` code does not create a label
   associated with your dropdownlist (clicking on it will not set
   focus)
2. The `ValidationMessageFor()` need to be applied to the property your
   binding to, not the `SelectList`
3. Delete you `ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(..)` code. Your have
   already assigned the selectlist to the `ApplicationRoles` property
   (and you should never need `ViewBag` if have a view model anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declare that only HttpGet methods are allow in that method of the controller. Thats why

Comment: Thank you guys all of you, it's working as 
 @StephenMuecke  responsed